# GMock doesn't match EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a mocked function that when I run in a unit test with the anything matcher ('_') the unit test fails because GMock can't find a matched function.

Here is my mocked class and function:

```
class MockedClass {
public:
    MockedClass() {};
    ~MockedClass() {};
    MOCK_METHOD1(unregisterClient, bool(const ThriftClient& tClient));
};

class ConnectionClass {
public:
    ConnectionClass() {};
    ~ConnectionClass() {};

    bool unregisterClient(ThriftClient& tClient)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        if (mock_ != NULL)
            ret = mock_->unregisterClient(tClient);
        return ret;
    }

    static MockedClass *mock_;
};

MockedClass *ConnectionClass::mock_ = NULL;
```

Here is the function under test:

```
class RealObject {
public:
    RealObject(ConnectionClass &cc);
    void unregister();

private:
    ConnectionClass &cc_;
    ThriftClient tClient_;

}

RealObject::RealObject(ConnectionClass &cc) {
    cc_ = &cc;
}

void RealObject::unregister() {
    cc_->unregisterClient(tClient_);
}
```

Here is the test function:

```
TEST_F(Test, UnregisterTest) {
    MockedClass mclass;
    ConnectionClass cc;
    cc.mock_ = &mclass;
    RealObject obj(cc);

    EXPECT_CALL(mclass, unregisterClient(_)).WillOnce(Return(true));

    obj.unregister(); // Calls mocked function
}
```

Here is the failure message:

> Test.cpp:142: Failure Actual function call count doesn't match
>
> EXPECT_CALL(mclass, unregisterClient(_))...
>
> Expected: to be called once
>
> Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

I have also tried:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mclass, unregisterClient(Matcher<const ThriftClient&>(_))).WillOnce(Return(true));

EXPECT_CALL(mclass, unregisterClient(An<const ThriftClient&>())).WillOnce(Return(true));
```

All with the same failure message.

Why am I getting this failure message? I don't understand why GMock can't match the function call.

Comment: You are calling `cc_->unregister` and should be calling `unregisterClient`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: Everything in ConnectionClass being private is also a typo? Have you run this exact code?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thank you.

Comment: I would double check for differences between the code you have posted and your real code. As a side note, you should be using member initialization list, instead of assignment in `RealObject`'s constructor. That code won't compile as is. If `RealObject::cc_` is not a reference, but an instance in your real code, that would explain the test result.

Comment: Did you change your design yet? Or you found an answer to your question?

Comment: I have not found an answer.

Comment: I have seen a similar behaviour and searching for a solution. In the above case if i create a dynamic mock object(raw pointer in the test fixture class and intentionally don't delete the pointer in the destructor ) then i get the expected call but with memory leak. I appreciate your valuable feedback.